# Does Transaction Isolation Level Have to be Reset After Read

Tags: sql, transactions, dirty-data, dirtyread

I am trying to dirty check a SQL Server table, but I am not sure whether or not the settings are saved to the table and will effect other reads, or automatically reset after the read. I would like the `uncommitted` flag to only be used each time the procedure is called, and not effect other reads to the table.

**Case 1**:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select * from table
```

**Case 2**:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select * from table
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

Is the last line in Case 2 necessary?

Comment: When you are giving table hint, you do not need to turn it off, as these settings are at default  database level

Comment: For more info refer to https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-t-sql-transaction-isolation-levels-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: The answer is **yes**, *only if you want to*; but use `from [table] with (nolock)` in such simple scenarios.